# Disable JButton after click and enable when it done it's job

Tags: java, swing

I have a JButton which has an ActionListener, which does its job as many times as I click it. Below is my code:

```
   mouseListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
                source.setEnabled(false);
                try {
                    RequestCommon.ctbCookie = jtf.getText();
                    System.out.println(RequestCommon.ctbCookie);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = HttpURLConnectionBuilder.getConnection(RequestCommon.login, RequestCommon.getCtb888Headers());
                    String connectionOuput = HttpURLConnectionBuilder.getConnectionOuput(connection);
                    System.out.println(connectionOuput);
                    new Player(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("sounds/8.mp3")))).play();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JavaLayerException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                source.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    jb1.addActionListener(mouseListener);
```

I want it so that no matter how many times I click while the job is running it won't execute again. When the job is done, if I click again, the job will run again. I don't know how to do that, please tell me if you know, thanks!

Comment: Does your problem lie in disabling the button in general, or is the problem, that you don't know when to call the disable-command?

Comment: does the listener on mouse ? 
or on the button ?

Comment: it seems that your code will work fine

Comment: The thing is, if `play()` is an asynchronous method, then you'll enable the button too early.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi on the button "jb1"

Comment: @grape_mao if I commont the play() and use    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3); It's the same .

Comment: @Jaycee You mean you can still click on the button even it is disabled? Another way to do is set a flag when your task is running, and check this flag to see if you should run it. (this will only work when you can reset the flag at the end of the task.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long running code should NOT execute on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You need to start a separate Thread to do you HTTP request.

The easiest way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker`. You can disable the button before you start the worker and then the worker has a `done()` method that is invoked and you can enable the button.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT and a working example of a Swing worker.

Edit:

People seem confused about event handling. The listeners for an event are invoked before the next event is handled. So in the case of "double clicking" on the button. The button is disable on the first click and the long running task is started. The second click is then received on the disable button so the ActionListener is not invoked.

Here is some old code I have lying around which was written before a SwingWorker existed. The basic logic for the "Start in New Thread" button is:

1. disable the button so it can't be click while processing is happening
2. simulate a long running task by looping 10 times and sleeping
3. enable the button so the task can be done again

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*
* A couple of notes about long running tasks and GUI updates:
*
* 1) all GUI painting should be done in the event thread
* 2) GUI painting is not done until the event thread processing is done
*
* This means that long running code (database access, file processing ...)
* should not be done in the event thread. A new thread can be created for
* these tasks.
*
* Most Swing methods are not thread safe. If the long running task needs
* to update the GUI for any reason then the SwingUtilities class
* should be used to add code to the event thread.
*
* See the Swing tutorial on "Using Threads" for more information
* http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/threads.html
*/
public class InvokeLaterTest extends JFrame
    implements ActionListener, Runnable
{
    JLabel status;
    JButton eventThread;
    JButton newThread;
    JButton stop;
    Thread thread;
    int i;
    boolean stopProcessing;

    public InvokeLaterTest()
    {
        status = new JLabel( "Ready to Process:" );
        status.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
        getContentPane().add(status, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        eventThread = new JButton( "Start in Event Thread" );
        eventThread.addActionListener( this );
        getContentPane().add(eventThread, BorderLayout.WEST);

        newThread = new JButton( "Start in New Thread" );
        newThread.addActionListener( this );
        getContentPane().add(newThread, BorderLayout.EAST);

        stop = new JButton( "Stop Processing" );
        stop.addActionListener( this );
        getContentPane().add(stop, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //  Code is executing in Event thread so label will not be updated
        //  and the Stop button will not be enabled.

        if (e.getSource() == eventThread)
        {
            stopProcessing = false;
            run();
        }

        //  Code is executing in a new thread so label will be updated

        else if (e.getSource() == newThread)
        {
            stopProcessing = false;
            thread = new Thread( this );
            thread.start();
        }
        else
        {
            stopProcessing = true;
            status.setText("Processing Stopped");
            setButtons( true );
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        setButtons( false );

        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if ( stopProcessing ) return;

            System.out.println("ProcessingFile: " + i);

            // SwingUtilities makes sure code is executed in the event thread.

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    status.setText("Processing File: " + i);
                    status.paintImmediately(status.getBounds());
                }
            });

            // simulate log running task

            try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                status.setText("Finished Processing");
                setButtons( true );
            }
        });
    }

    private void setButtons(boolean value)
    {
        eventThread.setEnabled( value );
        newThread.setEnabled( value );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new InvokeLaterTest();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.show();
    }
}
```

A SwingWorker is similar to the above logic but:

1. you need to disable the button outside the SwingWorker
2. the worker will create the Thread for you and execute the code
3. when the worker is finished the `done()` method of the worker is invoked so you can enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if` and check if the button is enabled before executing your code.

```
  JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
 if(source.isEnabled()) {
                 .
.
. 
execute your code
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();

        if (source.isEnabled()) {
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(() -> {

                    source.setEnabled(false);

                    --your code here--

                    source.setEnabled(true);
                }
            );
        }
    };
```

Comment: (1-) GUI components should be updated on the EDT. The Thread is correct for the long running task, but you should not be updating the state of the button on that Thread. Use a SwingWorker, or you need to wrap the GUI code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to place the code on the EDT.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for your feedback, i didn't know, but tested my code and it was working for this usecase, although it may cause concurrency issues in other cases

Comment: Yes, in this simple case it will probably work. The problem is that you can have "random" results if you update the GUI on a non EDT thread. Trying to debug random events is a waste of time. So always make sure the GUI is updated on the EDT.

Comment: So how is it done properly? I tried putting in invokeLater and invokeAndWait and neither work. I can keep clicking the button and the actions are queued.

Answer (score -1):

Added a completedTime variable to hold the timestamp as when the action is complete, and every event has the time when it is generated, compare and return if it is less than the completed time

```
 long completedTime;

    mouseListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
                long timeStamp = e.getWhen();

                   if (timeStamp < completedTime) {

                       System.out.println("returned");
                       return;
                   }
               // source.setEnabled(false);
                try {
                    RequestCommon.ctbCookie = jtf.getText();
                    System.out.println( RequestCommon.ctbCookie );
                    HttpURLConnection connection = HttpURLConnectionBuilder.getConnection(RequestCommon.login, RequestCommon.getCtb888Headers());
                    String connectionOuput = HttpURLConnectionBuilder.getConnectionOuput(connection);
                    System.out.println(connectionOuput);
                    new Player(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("sounds/8.mp3")))).play();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JavaLayerException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
               // source.setEnabled(true);
                completedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    };
```

Comment: (1-) Long running code should NOT be executed on the EDT. A separate Thread should be used. There is no need to track the time.

Comment: I understand that longrunning task is to be run on swingworker, the problem here is how to avoid multiple clicks so that the long running process doesn't happen again and again.

Comment: `I understand that longrunning task is to be run on swingworker,` - your answer does not suggest that. `the problem here is how to avoid multiple clicks` - if you use the SwingWorker you don't have an issue. You disable the button before the worker starts. Then you enable the button in the done() method of the worker.

Comment: Let me ask you this, Before disabling the button, If I make multiple clicks. what will happen?

Comment: How can you double click before the button is disabled? The first click will invoke the listener which disables the button.

Comment: @camickr His code isn't correct for sure, but it's an interesting question, I don't know the low-level implementation, but what if we click several times before `actionPerformed` gets called, or maybe it won't happen at all, I'm confused...

Comment: Thanks , your method can solve my problem. However , it still get call and print "returned". May be **swingworker** works better. Anyway thanks a lot to let me know this method.

Comment: @grape_mao, `I don't know the low-level implementation,` - the listener is invoked when the event is received.

Comment: @camickr If you need to simulate the double click scenario, just put a debug inside the actionperformed may be on the swingutilities code,and try clicking the button again, this will post the event to the EDT, once the swingutilities completes, this method from the EDT will be Posted from the Queue.So disabling it is not a solution. The original code even disabled the button right.

Comment: @jaycee The sysout is just for referenece, you can remove it, it is not mandatory.

Comment: @camickr I know this. What I mean is imaging the computer is very slow...Between clicking on the button and the event is received, you can click a second time...is it just be ignored?

Comment: @grape_mao That is not ignored, that will call the swingworker again.

Comment: @Saran, `That is not ignored, that will call the swingworker again.` - yes it is ignored because the button is disable. Post your [mcve] demonatrating the problem if you think it works differently.

Comment: @camickr Do you believe the EDT is smart enough to ignore the event? Checking your code now

Comment: @camickr It is not ignored, to reproduce try putting breakpoints and test it. There are possibilities that we can click the button before it is disabled. you are missing that point.

Comment: No I am not missing the point. There is no need to use breakpoints. We are talking about a live application. The Swing worker is also irrelevant. All you need to test this is a frame with a button. In the ActionListener for the button the first statement will disable the button. Then the next statement is a simple System.out.println(...). You will see that even if you try to double click as fast as you can you will only ever see one line of output, You can't click on the button again until it is enabled.

Comment: Again post your [mcve] if you think it works differently. You statement means nothing without the code to back it up. I posted my example and the button is always disabled before you can click it again.

Comment: if swingworker is irrelevant, then why the original code where he disabled the button in actionperformed failed?

Comment: I don't know why the code isn't working because like you, he did not post an [mcve] so we don't know exactly what is happening. For example, maybe the `new Player()` code creates a new Thread to read the file, in which case the button is enabled immediately after the Thread is started. The point of my answer is that the design of the ActionListener is wrong. If you design it properly you won't have an issue.

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                status.setText("Finished Processing");
                setButtons( true );
            }
        });`

Comment: This Part saves from the issue. But when this will be posted to EDT decides that.
  
The cause for the issue is the mouse clicks are captured in the listener list, Once after the method completes,
the button is enabled, and the mouse click in the listener list is processed, since the button is enabled this causes the click event and actionperformed is trigerred.

By the way this was a very good discussion!