# How do I make an action perform once only?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a simple program where it counts your clicks per second. And I have done pretty much everything. The problem with me is that when I click the button, the timer starts and when I click again. The timer action performs again.

I want the timer to start only once so that when you press the button again, the timer action won't start repeatedly. I have tried to search online to make the timer start only once and there are probably answers but I can't understand them.

```
int counter = 0;
int secondsTimer = 5;
int object = 5;

String timer0 = "Timer: 0";

boolean ifRunning = false;

Timer timer;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
JButton button = new JButton("Click to Start!");
JLabel counterLabel = new JLabel("Clicks: 0");
JLabel timerLabel = new JLabel("Timer: 5");
JLabel cps = new JLabel("Cps: - ");

public Thing() {
    button.setFocusable(false);
    button.setBounds(100,160,200,160);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    
    counterLabel.setBounds(100,60,200,160);
    counterLabel.setVisible(true);
    
    timerLabel.setBounds(100,30,200,160);
    timerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    timerLabel.setVisible(true);
    
    cps.setBounds(250,60,200,160);
    cps.setVisible(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(420, 420);
    frame.setTitle("Click Speed Counter made by Sultan");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.add(counterLabel);
    frame.add(timerLabel);
    frame.add(cps);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void simpleTimer() {
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            secondsTimer--;
            
            timerLabel.setText("Timer: " + secondsTimer);
            
            if (secondsTimer==0) {
                timer.stop();
                cps.setText("Cps: " + counter / object);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==button) {
        button.setText("Click, Click!");
        
        counterLabel.setText("Clicks: " + counter);
        counter++;
        
        simpleTimer();
        timer.start();
        ifRunning = true;

        if (ifRunning = true) {
            ifRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable JButton after click and enable when it done it's job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396026/disable-jbutton-after-click-and-enable-when-it-done-its-job)

Comment: What Timer are you using? I'm quite sure the timer keeps a variable of whether it is running. If you can access that variable, you can use an if-statement to prevent triggering the `timer.start()` function while it is running.

Comment: *"there are probably answers but I can't understand them."* If you can't understand those answers, what makes us think you'll understand any we offer? Link to 3 of them, explain what it was about the answers you do not understand. Make no mistake, SO is not a help-desk or a place to find a tutor, the more effort seen in the question, the better the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are already keeping track of **ifRunning**.  In your actionPerformed method, you could add something like this right at the beginning...

```
if (ifRunning) {
    System.out.println("Already running! Not going to run again!");
    return;
}
```